# How to listen to live changes in firestore document in Flutter using scopeModel

Tags: flutter

I have a model set up as follows:

```
// scope.model.dart
mixin AuthModel on CoreModel {
  bool get isLoading => _isLoading;
  get notification => _notification;
  Observable<Map<String, dynamic>> profileUser;

  // constructor
  Future<void> authService() async {
    user = Observable(_auth.onAuthStateChanged);

    profileUser = user.switchMap((FirebaseUser u) {
      if (u != null) {
        authenticated.add(true);
        _isLoading = false;
        notifyListeners();
        return _db
            .collection('users')
            .document(u.uid)
            .snapshots()
            .map((snap) => snap.data);
      } else {
        authenticated.add(false);
        return Observable.just({});
      }
    });
  }

// get profile here
}
```

To get the user profile, I am doing something of this sort:

```
get profile {
   profileUser.listen((user) => _profile = user);
    if (_profile == null) {
      _isLoading = true;
      notifyListeners();
    } else {
      return _profile;
    }
  }
```

`_profile` is initiazed as an object!

Then in my screens or pages with scopeModel, I simply do

```
_model.profile['username'];
```

This works, the problem is when the firestore document information is changed, it doesn't change on the screen view, unless I change routes, or refresh the app.

I am new and struggling with flutter, what would be the right way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to use the FirebaseUser and want to keep track of the state 
or Logged in user throughout your app, i would suggest that you use the Provider on the highest level of your app.

For me its the easiest using the [Provider Package](https://pub.dev/packages/provider) which is basically ScopedModel v2 according to some tutorials/videos

Example

```
void main() {

   runApp(MyApp());
   }

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  MyApp();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        StreamProvider<FirebaseUser>.value(
          stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.onAuthStateChanged, // Provider here
        ),
      ],
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: 'My App',
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        theme: ThemeData(
          primaryColor: Colors.green,
          primarySwatch: Colors.green,
          accentColor: Colors.yellow,
        ),
        home: MainPage(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MainPage extends StatefulWidget {
  MainPage({Key key, this.storage}) : super(key: key);
  final FirebaseStorage storage;
  @override
  _MainPageState createState() => _MainPageState();
}

class _MainPageState extends State<MainPage>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final user = Provider.of<FirebaseUser>(context); // gets the firebase user
    bool loggedIn = user != null;

    return loggedIn ? HomePage() : LoginPage(); // Will check if the user is logged in. And will change anywhere in the app if the user logs in
  }
}
```

Additional References (This helped me)

[Fireship 185 Provider](https://github.com/fireship-io/185-advanced-flutter-firestore)

[Great Youtube video explaining the code](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vFxk_KJCqgk)